# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't apply changes unless I clean / rebuild the solution first

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, telerik

I've stumbled upon a really annoying issue with Visual Studio 2012.
Scenario:
I am developing a Windows Phone 8 App, in C#, with `Telerik RedControls` wizard.
If I apply a change to the XAML and press `F5` / `Build and Launch` / Launch the emulator or Device it won't reflect the changes I did.
In order to make the changes show, I have to either `Clean` or `Rebuild` the project before launching it.

This doesn't seem to happen with an empty project (C# / WP8) without Telerik, but the same problem happened also in the past in other projects, possibly it might be linked to referincing DLLs, but it doesn't always happen when referencing DLLs either (SQLite didn't seem to cause issues in another previous project).

Browsing the net I tried all the steps provided in what I found on StackOverflow and other websites:

1. `Tools >> Options >> Project and Solution >> Build and Run >> Check that "On run, when projects are out of date" is set to "Always build" or "Prompt to build"`
2. `Build >> Configuration Manager >> Check that "Build" is checked for all of the projects you want to build for each of the configurations you need to use.`
3. I tried Setting the Build option's platform to `Any CPU / x86 / ARM` but the result is always the same

This is extremely annoying because I am unable to code & see the effects, and sometimes I don't know if something is working or not cause of this.

If I had to take a guess it might be something related to the references added by Telerik (in this case), but I am really at a loss of solutions.

Comment: Are your files on a network share?

Comment: No, just on my local folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that when you create a Windows Phone application project that has an empty space in its name (as example "The Project"), Visual Studio breaks and does not correctly track the changes in the project files to invalidate them when building.

Comment: This is definitely the cause of the same problem that I had. Thank you. The project was working fine and suddenly started to have this issue probably after I installed some updates. Renaming the project to remove the space did not solve the problem.  I had to create a new project with a name without any space, then copied the code from the old one.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and after checking kinds of settings and configurations what finally fixed the issue was I:

- Switch to `Release` mode and ran the application. Everything rebuilt and worked fine.
- Then switched back to `Debug` mode and ran the application and everything was back to normal.

My only guess is that somehow Visual Studio 2012 got stuck in an incorrect state and this forced a refresh.